# How to use Selenium to click on the link in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on the number of likes. I tried to use

```
driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_1h').click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="_5p-9 _5p-l" and @id="u_0_1h"]')
```

However, both give the error:

```
 no such element: Unable to locate element.
```

How to solve this problem?

```
<div class="scrollAreaColumn" id="u_0_1f"><span class="_10tn" 
data-store="{&quot;reactionType&quot;:1}" data-sigil="reaction_profile_sigil">
<span aria-label="24K Like" class="_5p-9 _5p-l" role="button" id="u_0_1h">
<i class="_2ep2 img sp_so7iNrBRN80 sx_084697"></i>
<span data-sigil="reaction_profile_tab_count">24K</span></span></span>
<span class="_10tn" data-store="{&quot;reactionType&quot;:7}" 
data-sigil="reaction_profile_sigil"><span aria-label="2.9K Sad" 
class="_5p-9 _5p-l" role="button" id="u_0_1i"><i class="_2ep2 img 
sp_so7iNrBRN80 sx_50972c"></i><span data-
sigil="reaction_profile_tab_count">2.9K</span></span></span>
<div class="_10tl" style="background: rgb(88, 144, 255)
```

Comment: Most probably the id `u_0_1h`, is ever changing right?

Comment: Do you see exactly the same `@id` value after page refresh?

Comment: I would locate using `reaction_profile_tab_count`. Seems unique and stable

Comment: No, the id is still the same after refreshing the page.

Comment: How to use reaction_profile_tab_count?

Comment: try this //span[@data-sigil='reaction_profile_tab_count']

Comment: @Ankur, there is no effect.

Comment: did you try to add `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` before those lines?

Comment: @Andersson, I tried but still the same

Comment: I want to try this: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@i class="_2ep2 img sp_so7iNrBRN80 sx_084697"]').click() but there is a space between "i" and "class". How to solve it?

Comment: you can't use this bec i is a tag not attribute .. //span/i[@class='_2ep2 img sp_so7iNrBRN80 sx_084697'] try this

Comment: @Ankur, it does not work. Thank you very much for your effort and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To click on the number of likes i.e. **`24K`** you can use the following line of code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='scrollAreaColumn' and starts-with(@id,'u_0_')]/span[@class='_10tn']/span[@class='_5p-9 _5p-l' and contains(@aria-label,'Like')]//span[@data-sigil='reaction_profile_tab_count']"))).click()
```

Comment: Though a bit complicated, it works. Thank you very much. DebanjanB.

Comment: When I put class1 = "'_10tn'", and replace '_10tn' by class1. It does not work. That is, WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='scrollAreaColumn' and starts-with(@id,'u_0_')]/span[@class=class1]/span[@class='_5p-9 _5p-l' and contains(@aria-label,'Like')]//span[@data-sigil='reaction_profile_tab_count']"))).click()

Comment: See the application you are automating is based on _ReactJS_, hence the _xpath_ was crafted considering a lot of pros & cons to cater to your specific need. I am not sure why you want to tweak the attributes. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. SO volunteers will be happy to help you out.